# How to filter motion vectors?

Tags: ffmpeg

My video is very noisy temporally.  The video was taken under low light conditions at a high frame rate.

Currently I've tried

```
ffplay -flags2 +export_mvs -i test.mp4 -vf edgedetect=low=0.05:high=0.17,hqdn3d=4.0:3.0:6.0:4.5,codecview=mv=pf+bf+bb,"lutyuv=y='if(lt(val,19),0,val)'
```

The motion vectors are tracking noise as in the near dark areas the vectors varying greatly in magnitude and angle.

How do I decimate or filter the display motion vectors based on magnitude and/or location?

Comment: I’m not sure there is a way to do that (maybe there is, I just don’t know it) but is there a reason you can’t denoise prior to encoding?

Comment: @szatmary I've tried various filters like `hqdn3d` `atadenoise` and debanding to very limited effect but there is just too much noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that `codecview` will display the motion vectors *from the encoded file*, so if you denoise that file after decoding (such as `ffplay [..] -vf hqdn3d`), then the motion vectors aren't actually affected by the denoising, because they come from an earlier part in the pipeline.

To change the motion vectors in the compressed file, you need to re-encode it and denoise/degrain before encoding. I don't remember if there's a way to generate motion vectors (post-decoding) within the filter chain.